# Authenticate MISP with Openldap

Tags: authentication, openldap

I am trying to authenticate MISP through LDAP, but I am not able to do it. I havve tried to look into the logs but I did't get anything.

What should happen is the following:

Connect to the misp web URL in your browser
The Apache web server asks for basic authentication. In most browsers a pop-up window will appear asking you for a username and password.
You will then be redirected to the MISP event page, no login is required. But in this step I got: **ERROR " INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"**

My configuration is the following one:

In the file httpd.conf I added the following:

```
<Location "/">
 
        # Basic authentication with LDAP against MS AD
 
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPURL ldap://xxxx:389/dc=xxxx,dc=xxxx?cn?sub
        AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=Manager,dc=xxxx,dc=xxxx"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxxxxxx"
        AuthLDAPInitialBindAsUser on
        Require valid-user
 
</Location>
```

In the file /var/www/MISP/app/Config/config.php I added the following:

```
'ApacheSecureAuth' => array(
                        'apacheEnv'          => 'REMOTE_USER', 
                        'ldapServer'         => 'ldap://xxxx',
                        'ldapProtocol'       => 3,
                        'ldapNetworkTimeout' => -1,  
                        // Note that we need a service account here.
                        'ldapReaderUser'     => 'CN=Manager,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx', 
                        'ldapReaderPassword' => 'xxxx',
                        'ldapDN'             => 'OU=xxxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx',
                        'ldapSearchFilter'   => '', // I don't use that. Maybe you should
                        'ldapSearchAttribut' => 'uid',  // Make sure this match and works for you
                        'ldapFilter'         => array('mail',),
                        'ldapDefaultRoleId'  => 3,   // this will create users
                        'ldapDefaultOrg'     => '1',      // uses 1st local org in MISP if undefined,
                        'ldapAllowReferrals' => false,   // allow or disallow chasing LDAP referrals - see what$
                        'ldapEmailField' => array('mail'), // whatever works for you
        ),
```